# Insert element into list at specific index

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I insert an item into a list at a specific index? Without using:

```
index = 3
list = [:3] + [item] + [3:]
```

Help!

Comment: You want `list.insert`?

Comment: I guess you meant `list = list[:3] + [item] + list[3:]`?

Comment: I don't want to type `list = [:3] + [item] + [3:]` all out

Comment: you can just write `lst[3:3] = [item]`

Comment: Who should accept as best answer? I'll go with the top one

Comment: I would say the first one... seems fair. Anyway you have here a duplicate question with 3 identical answers. That goes against the principle of this website...

Comment: then with Math Coder 101 or Ann Zen?

Comment: Ok Math Coder 101 was at the top so i chose him

Comment: the order of equally scored answers is random. Not willing to take anything from anybody, but @AnnZen answer is a tad better, since it is not overriding the built-in name `list` (which is an issue your original code is also presenting), and it also provides some link to the relevant official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `list.insert function`:

```
list.insert(index, element)
```

Comment: Yes, this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [insert](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
lst.insert(2,'d')
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['a','b','d','c']
```

Comment: Also works, and was useful.

Comment: I think it was an edit clash, sorry

Comment: @Adam what do you mean *also works*? It is exactly the same as the other answer...

Comment: Anyway it is better to link official docs when possible and to name the code "correctly", e.g. [`list.insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: @Tomerikoo that is true... Both answers helped

Comment: I am sure they are happy for you, but then people may perceive this as a potential conflict of interest, and perhaps you should also disclose your affiliation status.

Comment: @norok2 when you print(lst.insert), you get "<built-in method insert of list object at 0x00E837E8>", which is what I said, it's a method.

Comment: Sure, but surrounding it with apices signals others that it is actual code, not just a word. Then, if it is a method, it is a method of a class, so why not writing the name of the class directly? Finally, people not familiar with OOP nomenclature may find easier to associate it to a callable if you also include parentheses.

Comment: @AnnZen It means that I assume that whoever wrote the website you mentioned is happy that you appreciate their work.